# Using subscription for the iteration variable in Python for loop

Tags: array, python

I just realized that Python allows more than names as `for` loop iteration variables:

```
for a[i] in sequence:
    pass
```

The real fun begins when `a` and `i` change during the loop. The following function inverts a list `a` in place while printing the intermediate steps. **All assignments occur implicitly in the iteration variables:**

```
def reverse_list_with_log(a):
    print(a)
    print("\n".join(str(a) for (i, (a[i], a[~i])) in enumerate(zip(a[::-1], a[:len(a) // 2]))))

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
reverse_list_with_log(a)
assert a == [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
[9, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Equivalent normal version:

```
def reverse_list_with_log(a):
    print(a)
    for i in range(len(a) // 2):
        (a[i], a[~i]) = (a[~i], a[i])
        print(a)
```

Could you come up with other creative uses of this "feature" (a subscription as the iteration variable)? No explicit assignment allowed (i.e., `a = b`) in the main treatment. Please give the readable version along with your proposition.

**Disclaimer.** This is my first question on this site, and I am aware that I cannot really set an objective winning criterion. However, I have seen in other questions that the variety of ideas and solutions frequently deserves reading beyond the winning answer. Feel free to improve or close my question if it cannot be salvaged.

Comment: I think this could work as a tips question asking whether this has golfing applications.

Comment: In the meantime, I am voting to close because of no objective winning criterion

Comment: I don't intend for this to sound harsh, but in the future if you intend to ask a question on a site and you know that your post isn't exactly on topic, please post on meta first.